# Form is clearing blank inputs prev set data

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, input

I can't seem to figure out why my form clears prev data when submitting. I have an edit button that when clicked pops open a form. If I edit the name field but not the birthdate field, the name is changed and the birthdate blanks out. It may be a simple silly error but a 2nd set of eyes may help

```js
class Card extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dataEditingMode: false,
      planetSelection: this.props.homeWorld,
    }
  }

  onEditDeets() {
    this.setState({
      dataEditingMode: !this.state.dataEditingMode
    });
  }

  onSaveDeets(element) {
    element.preventDefault();

    this.props.onSavingEditedDeets(
      this.props.id,
      this.refs.personName.value,
      this.refs.personBirthday.value,
      this.refs.personHomeWorld.value)

    this.setState({
      dataEditingMode: false
    });
  }

  onEditPlanetSelection(event) {
    this.setState({
      planetSelection:event.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {

    let getHomeWorld = (planetID) => {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.props.planetList.length; i++) {
        if (this.props.planetList[i].id === planetID) {
          return this.props.planetList[i].name;
        }
      }
      return 'planet does not exist.'
    }

    let name = this.props.name;
    let imageURL = this.props.imageURL;
    let birthday = this.props.birthday;
    let homeWorld = this.props.homeWorld;
    
    let dataEditingForm;

    if (this.state.dataEditingMode === true) {
      
      dataEditingForm = <form
      onSubmit={this.onSaveDeets.bind(this)}>

        <span>Name: </span>
        <input type="text" ref="personName" />
        <span>Birthday: </span>
        <input type="text" ref="personBirthday" />
        <span>Homeworld: </span>
        <select 
          value={this.state.planetSelection}
          ref="personHomeWorld"
          onChange={this.onEditPlanetSelection.bind(this)}
        >
            {this.props.planetList.map((planet)=>{
              return <option 
                          key={planet.id} 
                          value={planet.id}
                      >
                        {planet.name}
                      </option>
            })}
        </select>
        <button>Save Deets</button>
      </form>
    } else {
        dataEditingForm = <div></div>
    }

    return (
      <div className='card'>
        <div className='card-content'>
           <div className='card-name'>{name}</div>
           <img src={imageURL} alt='profile'/>
            <p>
                <span>Birthday:</span>
                <span>{birthday}</span>
            </p>
            <p>
                <span>Homeworld:</span>
                <span>{getHomeWorld(homeWorld)}</span>
            </p>
            <p>
                <span>
                  <button type="button" onClick={this.onEditDeets.bind(this)}>Edit Card Deets</button>
                </span>
            </p>

            {dataEditingForm}

        </div>
    </div>

    );
  }
}

export default Card;
```

Comment: I'm guessing the same happens to name when you just edit the birthday?

Comment: You are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you are updating your state based on the values of the form, irrespective of whether they are changed or not.

For a simple change, you can just set the default value of your `input` tags to the state

```
<span>Name: </span>
<input type="text" ref="personName" defaultValue="{name}" />
<span>Birthday: </span>
<input type="text" ref="personBirthday" defaultValue="{birthday}"/>
```

Also, in this case, I prefer performing edits like this based on the form state but depending on the scenario you would want to handle onChange.

For example, in a settings page, you might want certain toggles to be effective immediately. Then you should handle onChange and update the state directly.

Comment: doing so gave me this warning in the console. "Failed form propType: You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultValue`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`. Check the render method of `Card`."

Comment: Ohh yeah... My bad. I'm a little new to react myself :)

Comment: I changed it to defaultValue before seeing your edit and it worked! Thanks a ton.